# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry while running gradlew assembleDebug

Tags: android, gradle

When i run : `gradlew assembleDebug` command on android studio project root. Building process fails nad i get this message:

> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class

In my project there are two jar files: **slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar** and **slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar**. And both this jars contain two jars that includes **org.sl4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder**.

Here is my gradle file content which is located on app folder:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ias.caniasandroid"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    debugCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    debugCompile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

How can i fix the problem and run `gradlew assembleDebug`successfully without changing contents of jar files?

Comment: Don't use jars. Import artifacts from maven, conflicts are resolved automatically (if they can, mostly by picking the newest of all specified versions of an artifact).

Comment: Do you really need two libs *slf4j-log4j12* and *slf4j-android*? Or maybe one is enought. Try to use only one dependency instead of two jar files ` compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the below classes from `slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1` jar

```
org/sl4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
org/sl4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
org/sl4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
```

You can exclude particular class from a jar in gradle dependency.

To do it, unzip a jar using the `Copy` task, exclude the desired class and then add a file dependency on the extracted classes.

```
task unzipJar(type: Copy) {
   from zipTree('slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
   into ("$buildDir/libs/slf4j") //TODO: you should update this line
   include "**/*.class"
   exclude "org/sl4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class"
   exclude "org/sl4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class"
   exclude "org/sl4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class"
}

dependencies {
   compile files("$buildDir/libs/slf4j") {
      builtBy "unzipJar"
   }
}
```

**Note**: *It does everythime when your codes are compiling*.

On the other hand, if you don´t want to compile the package, but if you want to compile them and exclude from your JAR you could use

```
jar {
    exclude('org/sl4j/impl/**')  
}
```

Comment: My guess is that multiple versions of the same library have most classes common. Eventually you'll end up having a couple of unused obsolete classes from one version and everything from another. @bahtiyartan Removing one of the jars altogether is the way in this case.